# Cordova splash screen

Tags: css, ios, iphone, cordova, splash-screen

I setup everything in phonegapp application. After i drag and drop the CordovaLib.xcodeproj then change the splash screen inside my app icon & screen folder. But still app loading cordovaLib splash screen. So, i deleted screens from CordovaLib project and it's working. I have splash screen name as Default.png, Default@2x.png etc. But in config.xml file having some other name. But my app working with proper screens. Is i need to change in config.xml file.

[image]

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h_at_2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait_at_2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape_at_2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
```

Comment: Change your image file name as screen-iphone-portrait.png,screen-iphone-portrait-2x and replace into src="res/screen/ios/"

Comment: But my app is working without screen-iphone-portrait.png name

Comment: its showing the image or not?

Comment: It's showing image...

Comment: Be clear what image is now showing

Comment: My new splash screen image..After i deleted the phonegap images from cordovaLib, it's showing my image

Comment: Now whats the problem??

Comment: I'm asking is i need to change or not. Without changing it's working. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your config.xml should always point to the correct location of your splash screens.

Whilst Xcode will ignore config.xml when choosing splash screens, the Cordova CLI does not. Attempting to build and run using the CLI will fail.

In addition, services such as PhoneGap Build will fail to build your app, and even some plugins will cause random errors because of a malformed config.xml, where a path points to a non-existent file.

Comment: @user2967559 Change your config.xml to point to the correct splash screens that you want displayed.

Comment: The splash screens are displaying with proper image without change.

Comment: @user2697559 Yes, it will, but it doesn't matter - change it, otherwise you'll have problems later (see my answer).

Comment: @user2967559 Maybe, but without seeing the full folder structure I can't be sure. Just make sure that the full path is correct, and it should be good.